# The old main color of my App is still persistent - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, colors, themes

I'm working on a new brand UX/UI version of my app, on VS CODE. In this way, I changed my main color.
This color is a custom color (`Color(0xFFFF0033)`).
I'm using a ThemeProvider to change between light and dark Mode. It's working very well.
But for some elements, like TextButton or TextField, I still have the old color (`#BB86FC`).
I'm searching everywhere in all my folders with the HEXCODE of the old color, and I can't find anything.

Do you have any idea why this old color persists ?

*I don't know what part of code you may need.*

**EDIT : A perfect example, TextField is with the old color, but the ElevatedButton and bottom bar are with the new one.**

[image: preview]

**EDIT 2 : The code for the TextField Widget**

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(widget.maxLength)],
  maxLines: widget.maxLines,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
  onChanged: (value) {
    value = widget.textValue;
    setState(() {});
  },
  controller: widget.controller,
  cursorColor: Colors.white,
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  keyboardType: widget.keybordType,
  obscureText: widget.obscureText,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(widget.prefixIcon),
    labelText: widget.label,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: primaryFlashColor, width: 2)),
  ),
);
```

With `const Color primaryFlashColor = Color(0xFFFF0033);`

**EDIT 3 : ThemeProvider code**

```
const Color backgroundDarkColor = Color(0xFF000000);
const Color primaryTextColor = Color(0xFF1E1B1B);
const Color contrastDarkColor = Color(0xFF272A31);
const Color primaryFlashColor = Color(0xFFFF0033);
const Color customWhite = Color(0xFFe8e8e8);

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.system;

  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyThemes {
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Inter',
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: backgroundDarkColor,
    splashColor: primaryFlashColor,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(),
    primaryColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
    primaryColorLight: const Color(0xFFe8e8e8),
    toggleableActiveColor: const Color(0xFF454c56),
    buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(buttonColor: primaryFlashColor),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFFe8e8e8)),
    chipTheme: const ChipThemeData(
        backgroundColor: primaryFlashColor, disabledColor: contrastDarkColor),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      titleLarge: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, color: customWhite),
      titleMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 17.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: customWhite),
      titleSmall: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: customWhite),
      bodyLarge: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 10.sp,
          color: contrastDarkColor,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      bodyMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 10.sp, color: customWhite, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
      headlineLarge: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 10.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: customWhite),
      headlineMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 8.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: customWhite),
    ),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: primaryFlashColor,
            onPrimary: customWhite,
            textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)))),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          primary: primaryFlashColor // This is a custom color variable
          ),
    ),
  );

  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Inter',
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    splashColor: contrastDarkColor,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    primaryColorLight: const Color(0xFF121212),
    toggleableActiveColor: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFF121212)),
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      titleLarge: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 19.sp,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          color: const Color(0xFF121212)),
      titleMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 17.sp,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          color: const Color(0xFF121212)),
      titleSmall: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.sp,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: const Color(0xFF121212)),
      bodyMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.sp, color: const Color(0xFF121212)),
      headlineMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 8.sp,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
          color: const Color(0xFF121212)),
    ),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: contrastDarkColor,
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            textStyle:
                const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)))),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          primary: primaryFlashColor // This is a custom color variable
          ),
    ),
  );
}
```

For now, I'm just working on DarkMode, so it doesn't matter the LightMode ThemeData.

**EDIT 4 : With Widget Inspector, I can find this**

[image: Preview 2]

But how to change this ?

The problem persists even on Android Studio.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for something to be a color if it's nowhere in your project, (unless it's flutter's default colors). Are you sure you searched the project fully? Also keep in mind case sensitivy, like try searching both BB86FC and bb86fc, or do a case insensitive search to begin with

Comment: I did both. And yes, it does not make any sense ! Nothing works.
I'm editing OP.

Comment: That specific part would be defined in an `InputDecorationTheme` I believe. Maybe search for that word to see if it's set in some way

Comment: Nothing, I even manually changed the border color and width of the TextField but nothing changed. I've edited OP.

Comment: I would think it needs to be somewhere in a `ThemeData` class. But it's also hard to say without seeing the full code, but I also understand you can't really put your entire project's code in here

Comment: I add my `ThemeData` in OP.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out. Check [Screenshots](https://pixeldrain.com/l/RYXASpbi).
In main.dart, add primarySwatch:

```
theme: ThemeData(
   primarySwatch: Colors.pink
)
```

or if you want to create custom color pallete then check out [this](https://dev.to/rohanjsh/custom-swatch-for-material-app-theme-primaryswatch-3kic) post by Rohan Joshi.

and do not use useMaterial3: true, otherwise it won't work if you're using it.

Comment: I had hope.. but even after `flutter clean` and `flutter run`, I still have this old color...